# Best way to get the Page main title from a menu_branch in Refinery cms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms, refinery

I'm setting up a RefineryCMS site, I'd like to have the menu links showing the page full title on hover. In other words, every li element of the menu should be in this form:

```
<li><a href="/my_page_url" title="my_page_main_title">my_page_menu_title</a></li>
```

Where "my_page_main_title" is the one the admin enters at the top of the Page form and "my_page_menu_title" is the one in the advanced options.

I figured out I have to override `_menu_branch.html.erb`, but what should I put after `title:` ?

```
<%= link_to(menu_branch.title, refinery.url_for(menu_branch.url), title:  ) -%>
```

Thank you.

PS: I'm riding refinerycms-core v.2.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to display the page title as the title attribute and the menu title as the one in the link tag like this:

```
<a href='/my_page_url' title='Entered Top Of Page Form'>Menu Title</a>
```

Then you'd have to decorate the model and override the branch like so: https://gist.github.com/parndt/5147926

Comment: Is not working: I guess menu_branch.page_title is returning nil because there's no sign of the title attribute in the nav items.

Comment: After I told you which version of Refinery I was using and your consequent update, is now working.